# How to use .oct binary as function

Tags: binary, octave

I am trying to use a .oct binary file compiled by someone else as a function.

The binary file is `function.oct` and the file I'm running in octave is 'test.m`. They both exist in the same directory.

In trying to call `function.oct` in `test.m`, I'm doing the following:

```
test.m

autoload('func', 'function.oct')
func(x, y)
```

This results in this error:

```
error: /Users/octavetest/xyz/st.oct: failed to load: dlopen(/octavetest/st.oct, 10): Library not loaded: /Applications/Octave-6.1.0.app/Contents/Resources/usr/opt/octave-octave-app@6.1.0/lib/octave/6.1.0/liboctinterp.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/xyz/octavetest/st.oct
  Reason: image not found
```

How do I call the function from the compiled .oct file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you cannot use .oct binary files compiled by other users. OCT-files are linked with dependencies to the exact locations where Octave and other libraries are installed.

```
error: /Users/octavetest/xyz/st.oct: failed to load: dlopen(/octavetest/st.oct, 10): Library not loaded: /Applications/Octave-6.1.0.app/Contents/Resources/usr/opt/octave-octave-app@6.1.0/lib/octave/6.1.0/liboctinterp.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/xyz/octavetest/st.oct
  Reason: image not found
```

You are looking at an OCT-file (`st.oct`, not `function.oct`) that was compiled against the Octave.app distribution of Octave, version 6.1.0, and that is the only Octave that it will run against.

You'll need to get the source for that `st` OCT-file and recompile it in your Octave environment.

Sorry.